# Python shutil.move is copying on external hard drive

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

So, I have this python code that I'm using to move files into folders on an external hard drive. The weird thing is, `shutil.move` is copying the files, not moving them. Anyone know why it's doing this? I tested the code on the local system with fake files, and it successfully *moved* them, but on the external drive, it just *copied* them.

*For some context, I ran this code on another persons computer while remoting to it, their external hard drive was connected. It shouldn't make a difference, it's as if I were there in person running the command.*

Here's some of my code:

```
target_folder = root_folder + sponsor
if not os.path.exists(target_folder): 
    os.makedirs(target_folder)

target_file = root_folder + file_name
if os.path.exists(str(target_file)):
    shutil.move(target_file, target_folder)
```

Comment: Do you have permissions to `move` the file?  Maybe you only have read access to the external drive?  If not that perhaps it's how the OS sees the external drive (UNC vs mapped drive?)

Comment: That's a good point, perhaps the permissions are weird on the files on the drive. I'm not sure at this point, I'm don't have access to that persons computer at this time.